# Is my future husband fixed since I was born?

Tags: qadar, husband

According to Islam, has my future husband already been fixed from the day I born? Or will it change according to my decisions?

Comment: This is an opinion based answer which is not fit for this website . Please discuss your educational plans with your family and the proposals so you can come to a common understanding . Maybe you can get married and study with some arrangement to move in later on .

Comment: Everything that is to happen till Judgment Day has already being put down in the Loh e Mahfooz, fifty thousand years before the universe was created (we don't know if earth years or something else) ... but every year angels bring down your provision and deeds for the upcoming year & it is your sincere dua and/or repentance that can change them. Ofcourse, in the Loh e Mahfooz, it would already be there that you would make that dua to have the deeds for that year changed. It is a deep topic and  needs further knowledge of Islam to be fully understood.

Answer (score 1):

- If the human wants something to happen, but Allah does not want it to happen, that deed does not occur and does not occur. If this desire, which does not come into existence, is a good thing, the people see the reward of his intention.
- If the human wants something to happen and Allah wishes it to happen, that deed comes into existence and is created. Since the creation of this act is caused by the partial will of the human, the human is responsible for this act. A good deed will be rewarded, and a bad deed will be punished.
- Actions that are created only by the will of Allah, without any intervention of the people: In such actions, the partial will of the human does not interfere. Allah invents it so that they can be tested with gratitude or patience.

Marriage is a verb that sometimes falls into the second group. As a result of the people's use of their partial will, Allah creates what He wants. Sometimes there is a verb that falls into the third group. Allah marries His human to each other without disturbing their will. But in both cases, marriage is destiny.

Answer (score 0):

Allah has written the fate of everything. It will not change. Whatever decision you make is written there.

Islam doesn't restrict anyone from gaining knowledge, and doesn't have any law about marrying age. You have to choose a good husband for yourself, whether now or 5 years later. You cannot blame you parents if you choose a wrong man or you didn't voice your opinion about the groom when they get you one. [Hadith here](http://inthenameofallah.org/Muhammad%20&%20Virgins.html). So it doesn't matter when you marry, it will not change anything in fate. And it is not true that you will get bad husband if you marry lately.

Studying will only make you more knowledgeable and mature. It is totally up to you when you want to marry. But wherever you go, always follow Islam's law, so that your parents won't say "See this is why we didn't want you to study".

Answer (score -1):

Salam Alikom,

A woman in Islam can study and increase her cultural and intellectual level without a problem, if Fitna is avoided, if you feel that the place where you study doesn't present a danger on you and your religion, no guys approach you and you are not fascinated or have bad thoughts, then you can continue studying.

You also shouldn't confuse and mix studying with not getting married, and getting married with stopping your studies, you can propose to your husband that you want to study and finish your 3 years plan and given the right arguments the right guy for you will accept such condition without a problem if you feel that you can give your man and you home their rights.

As long as you obey Allah and you make the good decisions don't fear your faith, it will come to you in its best form and you'll be pleased, just make sure God and Islam's teachings always come first.

Be sure to choose the religious muslim man, and think of your priorities on the long term.

May Allah guide you.

Comment: Thank you so much everyone who answered my question.. all the explanations were really helpful for me to take my decision. may Allah bless you All